# I don't understand the usage of "out of"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, word-usage, word-order

> The burg was surrounded by two belts of walls: the first ran around the castle (the northern side of this belt is still well preserved today), while, **out of** the second belt, which extends around the citadel, only the main access gate has left.

What do you think about "out of" in that position?

Comment: 'Out of' meaning 'as a fraction of' is often acceptable, but I'd not use it here. ', while, of the second belt, which extended around the citadel, only the main access gate remains.'

Comment: And *has left* should be *is left*.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know how to select yours as the best answer... anyway, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The burg was surrounded by two belts of walls: the first ran around the castle (the northern side of this belt is still well preserved today), while, **out of** (= **from**) the second belt, which extends around the citadel, only the main access gate has been left.

**[out of](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/out)**

> *Indicating the source or derivation of something; **from**.*